# Setting active state of Twitter Bootstrap button radio group in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

Does anyone know how I could set the 'active' button of the button radio group in Twitter Bootstrap?

I am using ASP.NET 4 and the latest version of Twitter Bootstrap. I have an ASP.NET UpdatePanel, inside of which I have the button group. When any of the buttons are pressed, a command is executed server side. This causes a PostBack, which is what I believe causes the state of the group to be reset. What I would like is for the "selected value" to be set on the load of the page, as a value may already exist in the DB. If another button is clicked I would like the DB to be updated and for that button to stay the 'active' button after PostBack.

My UpdatePanel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPreference" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="btn-group" id="preferences" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="None" 
                          CssClass="btn btn-primary active" 
                                      OnClick="btnPreferenceNone_Click" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnPreferenceDislike" runat="server" Text="Dislike"
                          CssClass="btn btn-primary" 
                                    OnClick="btnPreferenceDislike_Click" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnPreferenceLike" runat="server" Text="Like" 
                  CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btnPreferenceLike_Click" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnPreferenceIntolerant" runat="server" 
                   Text="Intolerant" CssClass="btn btn-primary" 
                                      OnClick="btnPreferenceIntolerant_Click" />
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

The class 'active' causes a button to be selected in the radio group. According to your code-snippet, Button1 is the default value when the page is loaded. 
So to select a button based on the value of the callback, you need to identify which button is to be selected, then using the id of the selected button, you will use Javascripts addclass() method

Inside the callback method, your javascript will look something like -

```
$('button selctor').addclass('active');
```

You could also refer to - [Bootstrap Button Radio Group Default Value (Check Attribute) Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326230/bootstrap-button-radio-group-default-value-check-attribute-not-working/18346226#18346226)