# Bootstrap Button Radio Group Default Value (Check Attribute) Not Working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

After countless hours of research, I'm still dumbfounded on how to get the checked attribute working for button radio groups for Bootstrap. I'm trying to default "Excellent."

Even though I know for sure radio inputs are `checked` and not `selected`, I even tried `selected` and nothing works.

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="inputWalls" id="inputWalls" value="Excellent" checked>
    Excellent </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="inputWalls" id="inputWalls" value="Good">
    Good </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="inputWalls" id="inputWalls" value="Poor">
    Poor </label>
</div>
```

If clarification is needed, please let me know.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In twitter bootstrap, you will indicate the default value using the 'active' class. 
So, for your example, if you are using Twitter Bootstrap, the following code will use Excellent as default checked.

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default **active**">
        <input type="radio" name="inputWalls" id="inputWalls" value="Excellent" checked>
    Excellent </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="inputWalls" id="inputWalls" value="Good">
    Good </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="inputWalls" id="inputWalls" value="Poor">
    Poor </label>
</div>
```

When you toggle over the buttons, you add/remove the class - 'active' from the label's class.

For an example, check this out - http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons - Radio

Comment: It seems when data-toggle="buttons" is used, the radio buttons' checked status no longer got updated when the radio button is clicked. Is this a bug a desired feature? If this is desired, then how to tell the backend which radio button is checked?

Comment: @QianChen Ping. I have this issue in BS3 too.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the question and answer are using bootstrap 3.0. I had the same question but with bootstrap 2.3.

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <button class="btn active"> Option 1</button>
    <button class="btn"> Option 2</button>
    <button class="btn"> Option 3</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Two things:

1. You should use different IDs for each of your `<input>` elements -- they're supposed to be unique!
2. Your example works for me! Check it out at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RAyNC/)!

Comment: I'm using their buttons: http://i2.minus.com/iAOC5Nv1KlDa3.png It's still not working.

Comment: Bootstrap buttons are meant to be used with buttons, not as a segmented control. In your screenshot, you're hiding the actual inputs. Default bootstrap behavior [is here](http://jsfiddle.net/NhggS/1/).

In order to get it to work, you'll need either JavaScript or some complicated CSS. The JS method is way easier, and is [written up here](http://dan.doezema.com/2012/03/twitter-bootstrap-radio-button-form-inputs/).